# Hiding FloatingAction items when you scroll to the bottom of a list?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

So if you have a RecyclerView that extends to the end of the screen and use a FloatingActionButton or the third-party FloatingActionMenu, then there is a slight problem with cover-up: If you scroll to the end of the list, the floating button covers up part of the row and there is no way to see or get to what's underneath it.

Is there a way Android allows you to:

1. Detect if your list has a sufficient number of items in it, i.e. if there is a row at the bottom of the screen visible.

and

2. Slide the buttons out of the way if you scroll down to the very end, and then slide them back in if you start scrolling back up?

Edit: Or, alternatively, add dynamic padding to the end of the RecyclerView that only shows up if you've scrolled all the way down?

Comment: i'm trying to understand what you want, is it something like this : https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

Comment: Similar, yes, except just the FloatingActionButton, not the toolbar, and only when you're at the end of the list (so the button doesn't cover up the row). Or if there's a way to invoke `view.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);` on the RecyclerView when it's at the end (but I don't know if there's a clean way to do this without it appearing jumpy)

Comment: How can I provide a screenshot of something I can't implement? I'm just trying to hide the button when scrolling to the end of a list so the last item in the RecyclerView isn't covered up, where the total number of items in the list >= the number of items that can fit in the view at one time (no sense in hiding the button if it's not covering anything)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common pattern to solve the problem of covering up parts of UI is to hide FAB as soon as the user starts scrolling down ... You can achieve this by this code fragment (used with RecyclerView):

```
    fDemandsRv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if(dy > 0 ){
                if(fFab.isShown()) fFab.hide();
            } else {
                if(!fFab.isShown()) fFab.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

If you insist on hiding it on the very end and you are using RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager, you can check method `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` on the LayoutManager object during the OnScrollListener callback ...

Comment: Not quite what I was after to begin with but this it solves the problem and actually seems to work; thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. The solution was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40215706/6507689).
The main idea behind it is that `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` is overriden and changed, so that it reacts to `RecyclerView` and `CoordinatorLayout` scrolling.

However, in your case `RecyclerViewScrollListener` must be different. Here is the implementation:

```
private class RecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    FloatingActionButton mChild;

    public RecyclerViewScrollListener(FloatingActionButton child) {
        this.mChild = child;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && recyclerView.canScrollVertically(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            mChild.show();
        } else {
            mChild.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            mChild.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

When filling `RecyclerView` with data, invoke such function on it in order to disable or enable scrolling:

```
private void changeCoordinatorLayoutScrollPossibility(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (recyclerView.getMeasuredHeight() < alertsRecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange()) {
                recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            } else {
                recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you actually apply it to the current RecyclerView / FloatingActionButton? addOnScrollListener?

Comment: Yes. the way, how to do it is inside the link I provided.

Comment: If there is only (for example) one item in the list, then the button hides for good and never comes back

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Does not work unfortunately; button still gone for small lists. Unless I have to call this in some specific order?